# Puedo crear varios arrays a partir de otro ArrayList?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Tengo un arreglo que se llama `<listaMaterias>` que almacena las materias de una escuela, el punto es que cada vez que le añada un elemento ( una materia) a ese arraylist quiero que me cree otro arraylist para guardar los estudiantes de dichas materias, así, si quiero imprimir los estudiantes de una sola materia se muestren únicamente los de dicha materia y no todos los que haya introducido en general para todas las materias, no se si me explique bien. Muchas gracias.  Pongo lo que tengo hasta el momento...

```
java
// Arraylist de las materia o asignaturas
public ArrayList<Programa> listaprogramas;

// el método que agrega las materias
 public void addPrograma(Programa programa){
       listaprogramas.add(programa);
   
    }
// EL arreglo que enlista los estudiantes
public ArrayList<Estudiantes> listaEstudiantes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible.
Entiendo que puedes tener una clase algo asi:

```
class Escuela{
   // Arraylist de las materia o asignaturas
   public ArrayList<Programa> listaprogramas;
   // el método que agrega las materias
   public void addPrograma(Programa programa){
       listaprogramas.add(programa);
    }
   // EL arreglo que enlista los estudiantes
   public ArrayList<Estudiantes> listaEstudiantes;
}
```

en lugar de tener tu lista de estudiantes dentro de la clase escuela, la lista deberia estar dentro de la clase Programa y tendrias las clases asi:

```
class Escuela{
       // Arraylist de las materia o asignaturas
       public ArrayList<Programa> listaprogramas;
       // el método que agrega las materias
       public void addPrograma(Programa programa){
           listaprogramas.add(programa);
      }
 }
```

Clase programa:

```
class Programa{
  String programa;
  // EL arreglo que enlista los estudiantes
  public ArrayList<Estudiantes> listaEstudiantes;
}
```

al momento de crear tu objeto "programa" deberias considerar agregar la lista de los estudiantes:

```
Escuela escuela = new Escuela();
Programa programa = new Programa();
programa.Setprograma("Materia");
programa.listaEstudiantes.add("estudiante");
escuela.addPrograma(programa);
```

esto se cumple siempre y cuando tus estudiantes solo pertenescan a un unico programa, de lo contrario abria que rediseñar la logica y relacionar las clases como si se tratase de una Base de datos relacional.

Comment: Gracias te agradezco mucho la explicación, serías tan amable de indicarme como va lo la base de datos relacional?, ya que como dices si no pertenecen a un único programa la lógica no se cumple, ya que creo yo que es lo que tendré que implementar posteriormente. Eso si te vuelvo a agradecer mucho la aclaración de este problema.

Comment: Una base de datos relacional es un tipo de base de datos que se encarga de relacionar entidades (en este caso pueden ser las clases) para tener informacion ordenada y precisamente resolver este tipo de casos donde se repiten valores, y para no estar llenando de nuevo la información es que se crean estas relaciones.